# Counting the number of times an xslt transform is done

Tags: xml, xslt

Do to political reasons,  a customer wants me to implement a way to count the number of xslt transforms that are done on an xml document in a generic way instead of doing it another way.  I realize variables can't be changed once they are initialized according to a few forums, but if I understand correctly,  there is a work around using templates.  Although,  I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around it.

There would be 3 different types of counters: additions, modifications, and deletions.  I would like to output the counts to some sort of file.  I'm guessing a way to do this would be to use a second xslt based on the first.  But I'm having time understanding how to do counts with xslt.

### The original transform would look something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"[
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!--  copy identity -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!--  <xsl:template match="is_gone|@value"/>  -->
<xsl:template match="is_gone"/>

<!-- Adding an element -->
<xsl:template match="viral_desc">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      <blarg_group>17</blarg_group>
</xsl:template>


<!-- modification -->
   <xsl:template match ="some_test_value/text()[.&lt; 500]">500 </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match ="some_test_value/text()[.&gt; 2000]">2000 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Example XML data to transform

```
<class guid="a58bca48-cb0a-5f37-3a11-916e3a74959">
    <cork_id value="871222" valid="false"/>
    <merk_id value="11111" valid="false"/>
    <todd_id value="2188" valid="true"/>
    <name> Garp Toblabber </name>
    <classification>Sarcastic</classification>
    <is_gone>true</is_gone>
    <move>true
        <thingA>true</thingA>
        <thingB>true
            <subThingB>true </subThingB>
        </thingB>
    </move>
    <class_show_text> DA </class_show_text>
    <some_test_value> 3000 </some_test_value>
    <some_test_value> 3 </some_test_value>
    <some_test_value> 520 </some_test_value>
    <ew_tv_text> Drag </ew_tv_text>
    <standard_room_type> liquid </standard_room_type>    
    <viral_desc> Dull </viral_desc>
    <out_id euro_std="A" id="55" name="Nerf" environment="Volatile" category="Vague" modifier="Yes" is_out="false"/>
    <source/>
    <comments/>
</class>
```

### Desired output would look something like the following

```
<r>
<add> 1 </add>
<del> 1 </del>
<mod> 2 </mod>
</r>
```

Comment: How representative is your example? With what you show us, where all affected nodes are direct children of the root element, counting them is trivial. --- P.S. Which processor will you be using?

Comment: @michael.hor257k The example is a subset of the larger xml.  The xslt transform additions, deletions, and modifications are a small subset as well.  So there would be many of each type.  I would be using the .NET processor.

Comment: Is it for every file processed or a generic once in a while report? If you are looking for template reporting tools there are many built into editors like oXygen.

Comment: The transform is for the processing of xml files which are basically configuration files each for a different set of customers.  It is something that would be used pretty often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/class">
    <r>
        <add><xsl:value-of select="count(viral_desc)"/></add>
        <del><xsl:value-of select="count(is_gone)"/></del>
        <mod><xsl:value-of select="count(some_test_value[. &lt; 500 or . > 2000])"/></mod>
    </r>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your input example, will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<r>
   <add>1</add>
   <del>1</del>
   <mod>2</mod>
</r>
```

To make it more generic and count the designated nodes at any level, use simply:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <r>
        <add><xsl:value-of select="count(//viral_desc)"/></add>
        <del><xsl:value-of select="count(//is_gone)"/></del>
        <mod><xsl:value-of select="count(//some_test_value[. &lt; 500 or . > 2000])"/></mod>
    </r>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Would there be a way to count up the multiple nodes for each one?  Something like count(//viral_desc)+count(//other_addition) to get the necessary output?

Comment: Sure: either `count (//x) + count (//y)` or `count (//x | //y)` should work.

Comment: P.S. I am not sure what's your starting point here. You might want to consider keeping a base XMl document listing the nodes in each category, and using XSLT to generate the two stylesheets from this document.

Comment: I've just read about XMI, but I'm not sure if I have a good enough grasp to understand your statement.  The XML I'll be transforming is output by a tool that doesn't use XMI or a schema.  Although,  it should conform to a schema.  The XML modified and generated by my tool also stays XML(No HTML or other web tech).  
The XSLTs will eventually be generated by doing an xml diff on the two similar but different xslts.